# How to access icons from icons8.com in web application?

Tags: icons

I want to use icons from [icons8.com](http://icons8.com) website. How can I access the icons in my web application from [icons8.com](http://icons8.com)?

Answer (score 2):

Click on an icon and either download it using the `Download` button or press `Generate HTML` to get the HTML, and then put that in your code.

There's a dropdown to the left also to change the size and format. In addition down the right hand side of the page there are a load of buttons to change the colour and/or style of the icon.

Comment: @MadhaviShinde Ah great, I'm glad you managed to get it working!